# What if anything, is Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I keep hearing about Symfony 3, in particular the new directory structure, but I can find nothing about a release date. Are there plans to release a new major iteration of symfony?

Comment: To those who have down-voted this. I did look unsuccessfully a number of times for the answer to this on the symfony site before posting this question. Furthermore I feel the question is of interest to any symfony developer in my situation and it has received a good answer which has been upvoted by two people. Please reconsider your down-vote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a) I'm sick of getting down-voted for this - even almost a year and half later. I genuinely didn't know what symfony 3 was and couldn't find an explanation. b) SF3 has been released now, so I doubt this question will be of much relevance to anyone anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are plans but nothing definite yet.

The community section of the Symfony 2 site has plenty of information on these sorts of things.

From: http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html

```
The work on a new major version of Symfony starts whenever enough 
major features breaking backward compatibility are waiting on the todo-list.
```

The next major version will be 3.0.

The next major long term release will be S2.7 schedule for May of 2015.  I would not be surprised if serious work on S3.0 starts after that release but that is just a guess.  Check the development mailing list and chat rooms for more information.